# jquery ui slider comparing values after sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of the slider when value goes up or goes down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var valMap = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 
    var counter = null;
    var slider = $( "#slider" ).slider({
      disabled: false,
      animate: true,
      min: 0,
      max: valMap.length-1,
      values: [0],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#zomlevel" ).val(valMap[ui.values[0]] + "x");
        slider.slider("option", "animate", "slow");
        counter++;
        if(counter increments){
alert("COUNTER INCREMENTS");
}
if(counter decrement){
alert("COUNTER DECREMENTS");
}
      }
    });
});
```

If i slide the slider to the right it should increment and if i slide the slider to the left it should decrement. how can i do that in slider?

Comment: what is the purpose of valMap

Comment: Those are the values of my camera. Since it has 10x optical zoom. 1 is 1x zoom 2x zoom etc. I just need to know if the counter increments or decrements. When I move the slider to the left it should decrement and if i move the slider to the right it should increment.

Comment: Try http://plnkr.co/edit/eBJGVzwYzboEFlL1jLZK?p=preview

Comment: I'm not using counter for this solution a different approach is used

Comment: Perfect it works great!. Can you put it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: done posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
jQuery(function($){

    var valMap = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    var counter = null, value= 0;
    var slider = $("#slider").slider({
        disabled : false,
        animate : true,
        min : 0,
        max : valMap.length - 1,
        slide : function(event, ui) {
            //$("#zomlevel").val(valMap[ui.values[0]] + "x");
            slider.slider("option", "animate", "slow");
            counter++;

        },
        change: function(){
            var val = $(this).slider('value');

            console.log(val, value)
            if(value < val) {
              console.log('incremented')
            } else if(value > val){
              console.log('decremented')
            }
            value = val;
        }
    });


});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eBJGVzwYzboEFlL1jLZK?p=preview)